# Best practices for decoupling input from other scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an input script that translates touches to directions (Left, Right, Up, Down) with a magnitude (0-1) in the `Update` loop, and when an input is detected this script fires a `UnityEvent`:

```
public class TouchAnalogStickInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class AnalogStickInputEvent : UnityEvent<Direction, float> { }

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]
    [Tooltip("Fired when a successful swipe occurs. Event Args: Swipe Direction, A normalized input magnitude between 0 and 1.")]
    public AnalogStickInputEvent OnAnalogStickInput;

    void Update()
    {
        ...
        if (successfulInputDetected)
        {
            OnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm subscribing to this `OnAnalogStickInput` event from the Unity Inspector to call my `CharacterController2D.Move` method, which takes a Direction and a magnitude:

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Move(Direction movementDirection, float normalizedInputMagnitude)
    {
        // Move the character.
    } 
}
```

Then I have another `GameObject` that I wish to rotate using the same input script. so I've attached `TouchAnalogStickInput` and `SnapRotator` to this `GameObject`, subscribing the `OnAnalogStickInput` event to call `SnapRotator.Rotate`:

```
public class SnapRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Rotate(Direction movementDirection, float normalizedInputMagnitude)
    {
        // Rotate object.
    }
}
```

At this point I've come to realize **I'm no longer in charge of which game loops these methods are called from**, e.g. **I should be** detecting input in `Update`, using this input in `FixedUpdate` for movement, and perhaps in my case I'd like to do the rotation last in `LateUpdate`. **Instead** both `CharacterController2D.Move` and `SnapRotator.Rotate` are being fired from the `Update` loop that the input code runs in.

The only other option I can think of is perhaps refactoring the Input script's code into a method call. Then having `CharacterController2D` and `SnapRotator` call this method in the `Update` loop, executing movement/rotation in the `FixedUpdate` or `LateUpdate` loop as required, e.g.:

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TouchAnalogStickInput Input;

    private var mMovementInfo;

    void Update()
    {
        // Contains a Direction and a Normalized Input Magnitude 
        mMovementInfo = Input.DetectInput();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (mMovementInfo == Moved)
            // Move the character.
    } 
}
```

**My question is:** What's the best practice for decoupling scripts like these in Unity? Or am I taking re-usability too far/being overly afraid of coupling sub classes/components in game development?

### Solution

In case it's helpful for anyone else here's my final solution, in semi-sudocode, credit to Ruzihm:

**Utility class to store information about a detected input:**

```
public class InputInfo
{
    public Direction Direction { get; set; } = Direction.None;
    public float NormalizedMagnitude { get; set; } = 0f;
    public TouchPhase? CurrentTouchPhase { get; set; } = null;

    public InputInfo(Direction direction, float normalizedMagnitude, TouchPhase currentTouchPhase)
    {
        Direction = direction;
        NormalizedMagnitude = normalizedMagnitude;
        CurrentTouchPhase = currentTouchPhase;
    }

    public InputInfo()
    {

    }
}
```

**Input class:**

```
public class TouchAnalogStickInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class AnalogStickInputEvent : UnityEvent<InputInfo> { }

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]
    [Tooltip("Fired from the Update loop when virtual stick movement occurs. Event Args: Swipe Direction, A normalized input magnitude between 0 and 1.")]
    public AnalogStickInputEvent OnUpdateOnAnalogStickInput;

    [Tooltip("Fired from the FixedUpdate loop when virtual stick movement occurs. Event Args: Swipe Direction, A normalized input magnitude between 0 and 1.")]
    public AnalogStickInputEvent OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput;

    [Tooltip("Fired from the LateUpdate loop when virtual stick movement occurs. Event Args: Swipe Direction, A normalized input magnitude between 0 and 1.")]
    public AnalogStickInputEvent OnLateUpdateOnAnalogStickInput;

    private bool mInputFlag;
    private InputInfo mInputInfo;

    void Update()
    {
        // Important - No input until proven otherwise, reset all members.
        mInputFlag = false;
        mInputInfo = new InputInfo();

        // Logic to detect input
        ...
        if (inputDetected)
        {
            mInputInfo.Direction = direction;
            mInputInfo.NormalizedMagnitude = magnitude;
            mInputInfo.CurrentTouchPhase = touch.phase;

            // Now that the Input Info has been fully populated set the input detection flag.
            mInputFlag = true;

            // Fire Input Event to listeners
            OnUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputInfo);
        }

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (mInputFlag)
            {
                OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputInfo);
            }
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {
            OnLateUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

**Character controller that subscribes to the `OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput` event.**

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Move(InputInfo inputInfo)
    {
        // Use inputInfo to decide how to move.
    }
}
```

**Rotation class is much the same but subscribes to the `OnLateUpdateOnAnalogStickInput` event.**

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure of the best place to post this question. Can you tell me why this question is incorrect for Stack Overflow so I know for the future?

Comment: Actually, cancel that! I was under the wrong impression about the boundary lines between SE & SO  :)

Comment: SnapRotator and CharacterController also have Update() and FixedUpdate(). You can copy direction and magnitude to private variables and use them in Update()/FixedUpdate(). Maybe change script execution order to have TouchAnalogStickInput Update() called before the others.

Comment: Btw Unity questions go to Game Development usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one alternative, which mostly requires changes in your `TouchAnalogStickInput` class.

Set input state flags in `Update` and fire any relevant Events. Only this time, you fire an "OnUpdate" event (which in your specific case would not have anything registered to it):

```
void Update()
{
    ...
    inputFlag_AnalogStickInput = false;
    ...

    if (successfulInputDetected)
    {
        inputFlag_AnalogStickInput = true;
        OnUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag);
    }
}
```

And in `TouchAnalogStickInput.FixedUpdate`, call `OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput`, which would be registered with your `Move`

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...
    if (inputFlag_AnalogStickInput)
    {
        OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag);
    }
}
```

And so on with LateUpdate, which fires an event that your `Rotate` is registered with.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    ...
    if (inputFlag_AnalogStickInput)
    {
        OnLateUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag);
    }
}
```

These `OnFixedUpdateOn...` events, of course, fire on every `FixedUpdate` where that flag is true. For most cases--including for `Move`--that is probably appropriate, but in other situations that may not be desirable. So, you can add additional events which fire on only the first `FixedUpdate` occurrence after an update. e.g.:

```
void Update()
{
    ...
    firstFixedUpdateAfterUpdate = true;
    inputFlag_AnalogStickInput = false;
    ...

    if (successfulInputDetected)
    {
        inputFlag_AnalogStickInput = true;
        OnUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag);
    }
}



void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...
    if (inputFlag_AnalogStickInput)
    {
        OnFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag); 

    }
    if (inputFlag_AnalogStickInput && firstFixedUpdateAfterUpdate)  
    {
        OnFirstFixedUpdateOnAnalogStickInput.Invoke(mInputDirection, normalizedInputMag); 
    }
    ...
    firstFixedUpdateAfterUpdate = false;
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Fantastic! This will require minimal refactoring and still keep everything very nicely decoupled. 

When you talk about adding an additional flag for firstFixedUpdateAfterUpdate is this because FixedUpdate **might** run several times per frame, and there are situations/scripts which may only want to subscribe to the first of those fixed updates? Do you have an example of a script that may only want to run on firstFixedUpdateAfterUpdate?

Comment: Good question. I don't have any specific examples! It might come in handy for one-off debugging purposes, such as toggling some debugging option that shouldn't be toggled in the middle of `Update` or `LateUpdate`. I figured I'd mention it just as a possibility, even if it is an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look into customising [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) and having your gesture processor run before everything else.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take advantage of this script execution order mechanism in combination with Ruzihm's answer to make my logic more deterministic!